# Vpc peering and private link

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint, aws-vpc-peering

I have 3 VPCs (A, B, C) where VPC private link is established between A<-->B, and VPC peering is established between B<-->C.

Is it possible for instances in VPC A to reach VPC C via a VPC endpoint in VPC B?

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS documentation,

> A VPC peering connection is a one to one relationship between two VPCs. You can create multiple VPC peering connections for each VPC that you own, but transitive peering relationships are not supported. You do not have any peering relationship with VPCs that your VPC is not directly peered with.

This documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-basics.html#vpc-peering-basics-multiple

So the peering is *only* between B and C. With private link, you gave VPC A permission to hit a service via a VPCE in VPC B, but that's where it ends. It will not be able to reach VPC C in this current setup.

Comment: How about if from VPC A, we hit a load balancer in VPC B and then load balancer in VPC B sends traffic to instances in VPC C? Will it work with the same VPC setup?

Comment: @KaustubhGupta Yes, that would work. That would just be making an HTTP request your other VPC and would then allow you to take advantage of the VPC peering,